# Edges of large graphs not shown in default style

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to display a big graph with ~5000 vertices and ~5500 edges and given `VertexCoordinates`.
Without the coordinates the graph displays all edges. But with the given coordinates just a few edges are shown.

```
Graph[nodes, rels, VertexCoordinates -> coords]
```

I noticed that with `GraphStyle -> "Vintage"` the edges are shown.
I cannot reporduce the error on small test data sets:

Nodes: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/3a37ce26-c3a7-4a94-a0ed-7d4e41952b29

rels: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/bc960912-ff24-43bc-9dbd-04cf23bbcd70

coords: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/aab7a158-c370-417c-8d85-a4e9676bb336

**Edit / Solution** a simple `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` would have done it too

[image: default style]
[image: vintage style]

Comment: I only see 5052 coordinates, but 5062 vertices. Why don't you publish the variables to the wolfram cloud.

Comment: @M.R. published on WC and checked the length. It should work now.

Comment: You could set VertexSize -> 0

Comment: @halmir that fixes the problem. can you explain why?

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug.